# Swift Google Maps Location Direction When In Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, core-location, cllocationcoordinate2d

In my swift 5.7.2 and XCode 14.2 IOS app I have a simple Google Map View.

The map is showing correctly and as I move the camera is updating properly except the direction of the blue dot indicating where I'm heading when the iPhone is in landscape mode.

For example, as shown in the picture below, [image]

The arrow of the blue dot is pointing north. Indeed, north is the direction where the top of my phone is pointing when in portrait mode. However, if I rotate the phone, making it in landscape mode, the blue arrow is indicating exactly -90 degrees off.

I've tried using `animate` with a `toBearing` and a `viewingAngle`, it doesn't work properly and just rotates the map as I move around:

```
            var navView: GMSMapView! ## In View Controller
            var camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 1)
            let viewBounds = self.view.bounds
            navView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 102, y: 0, width: viewBounds.maxX - 205, height: viewBounds.maxY), camera: camera)
            navView.tag = 10
            navView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            navView.isTrafficEnabled = true
            self.view.addSubview(navView)
.....

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last!
        speed = abs(location.speed)
        altitude = location.altitude
        let coordinate = location.coordinate
        latitude = coordinate.latitude
        longitude = coordinate.longitude
        setSpeeds(speed, timeStamp: Int(UInt64(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970)))
        if((navView) != nil){
            let target = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            navView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition(target: target, zoom: 15, bearing: location.course, viewingAngle: 0))
        }
    }
```

What's the proper way of showing the correct heading when in landscape mode? Worst case scenario, if I can't forcefully set the heading +90 degrees when in landscape mode, is there a way to disable the heading and just show the blue dot?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely in landscape mode the top of the map is still North and the "top" (now side) of your phone is pointing North, so the arrow is correct. It wouldn't make sense for the arrow to point West.  Imagine you put your phone on the dash of you car in landscape mode. The direction of travel is towards the top, long side and that is where you would expect the arrow to point.

Comment: No. Suppose I put the phone horizontally (landscape) on the dash, the arrow will be pointing -90 degrees (where the short side of the phone is pointing) as compared to my actual direction of travel (where the long side of the phone is pointing)

Comment: Ok.  Have you tried this while moving or only while stationary? The phone will need direction of travel updates from GPS

Comment: Both stationary and travelling (walking and driving at 100km/h on open highway with no obstructions such as tall buildings nearby).